# NATURAL JOIN Syntax

Tags: sql, natural-join

```
SELECT*
FROM student NATURAL JOIN teaches
```

> 17:16:44  FAILED  [SELECT* - 0 rows, 0.023 secs]  [Code: 102, SQL
>   State: 42000]  Falsche Syntax in der Nähe von "teaches".

I really don't see the Syntax Error, what Problem could this be? Thanks in advance!

Comment: u need to add space between select and *

Comment: I tried it also with a space but it is not working. Maybe there is some Problem with the Server I am working on but the Syntax is Right.. I also tried with ";" after teaches

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: Simply forget about the NATURAL JOIN construction. Specify the JOIN conditions!

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use `natural join`.  Apparently, you have a database that doesn't support it.  So, use explicit `join` syntax:

```
SELECT . . . 
FROM student s INNER JOIN
     teaches t
     ON s.studentId = t.studentId;  -- I'm guessing what the keys are
```

The main problem with `NATURAL JOIN` is that it uses columns with the same *name*, rather than properly declared foreign key relationships.  The secondary problems are that the keys are not in the query -- making problems hard to debug.  Unexpected keys could be used for the join, and you can't even see what they are.  Be explicit on the keys you are using, by including them in an `ON` or `USING` clause.

Comment: @Optimal Google SQL tutorial

Comment: @Optimal . . . No.  Proper `JOIN` syntax would require an `ON` or `USING` clause (which your database might not support).